# Modal view using UIModalPresentationFormSheet doesn't autorotate when it's covered by another modal view using UIModalPresentationFullScreen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have three view controllers: `MainViewController`, `FirstModalViewController` and `SecondModalViewController`. All of them have implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

In `MainViewController`, I present a `FirstModalViewController` using `presentModalViewController:animated:` with modal style of UIModalPresentationFormSheet. Then, in `FirstModalViewController`, I present a `SecondModalViewController` using the same method but with modal style of UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

The problem is that after I rotate the device and then dismiss the `SecondModalViewController`, I notice the `FirstModalViewController` does not autorotate, but the `MainViewController` autorotate.

Why `FirstModalViewController` does not autorotate when it is covered by `SecondModalViewController`?

Comment: No. I ended up avoiding the problem by dismissing `FirstModalViewController` before presenting `SecondModalViewController`. After I dismiss `SecondModalViewController`, I present `FirstModalViewController` again. So there is always only one presented modal view.